# GraphView date labels are jumpy when scrolling horizontally

Tags: android, android-graphview

Look at the date labels in the GIF.
When a DataPoint is scrolled off screen its respective label also jumps off screen EVEN if they are much wider.
But the worst problem is that even other labels, of other DataPoints, jump and change their place.
How to make the labels scroll beautifully off screen?
**PLEASE PAY ATTENTION TO THE DATE LABELS AT THE BOTTOM OF THE SCREEN**
Thank you! [image]

Comment: there is no build-in solution for this issue in GraphView. You can fix in in the sources of GraphView and make a PR or take a look at alternative graph libraries

Comment: Thanks. what is PR? Public Relations? Product Review? Pasta Recipe?

Comment: PR = pull request

Comment: Try this: `setpadding()`, to whatever you feel is right for your labels and `setHorizontalLabelsAngle()` to 30 or 45. I haven't tried this solution but this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Is this acceptable?

[image: No jump labels]

As I mentioned in my comment above, this is what I did:

```
graphView.getGridLabelRenderer().setPadding(120);
graphView.getGridLabelRenderer().setHorizontalLabelsAngle(30);
```